# Could not load the appsettings.json file when function deployed to azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I am working on azure function app which references another project from core folder and that project contains the below class.

In this I am trying to read appsettings.json file and it works fine locally but when it's deployed to azure portal it could not find this file and builder.Build() method throws FileNotFoundException.

```
public static class ConfigurationSettings
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot GetConfigurationRoot()
    {

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me what wrong i am doing here and is there any other to include files in azure function apps?

Comment: Not an anser, but more of a tip. Don't use an `appsettings.json` file to load configuration values for your application. Use the proper functionality which is available, like the `ConfigurationManager` and use Application Settings, which are set either manual or via some deployment tool (like VSTS)

Comment: I created a custom provider after that i started getting the error "The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.11388\appsettings.json'." it's loooking for the file from where the code is being executed in the azure portal but i think it look for the file in the content root. Had it been normal .net core project i could achieve using IhostingEnvironment but not sure it will work in case of function app.

Comment: @Jan_V I know we should not use appsettings.json file but the thing is my project doesn't have any start up class and to bind some project settings this is the only way i am able to think right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Functions execute in Azure, `GetCurrentDirectory` is set to `D:\Windows\system32`. There's no `appsettings.json` in that folder, thus the exception.

I hope you are able to set the directory from which the library is loading settings. If so, you should add an extra parameter to your function of type `ExecutionContext` and use its `FunctionDirectory` property. See [docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function).

Of course, be sure to publish `appsettings.json` to Azure as part of your deployment.

Comment: appsettings.json is part of my function app which execute the run method but I am loading appsettings.json file from another class library. Once I published the functional app to azure all files and folders are getting copied including all the references, I can see files if I download content from portal but i still don't know what could be the path of appsettings.json once this get copied to azure and I am not sure if I can set some fix path for this file.

Comment: I think I got it, your answer worked for me just passed one more parameter ExecutionContext to run method and then I used FunctionDirectory property to retrieve file location.

Comment: If you copy the appsettings.json file, you should use `FunctionAppDirectory` property

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to run the function app and read the appsettings.json file. here is how i achieved this:

Created Custom Configuration provider CustomConfigurationProvider, assigned type to static property SettingsType and also embedded appsettings.json file in the class library project:

```
public class CustomConfigurationProvider : ConfigurationProvider, IConfigurationSource
{
    public static Type SettingsType;
    public override void Load()
    {
        var JsonString = GetResponse("appsettings.json");
        var jsonObject =  JObject.Parse(JsonString);
        foreach (var settingsGroup in jsonObject)
        {
            var settingsGroupName = settingsGroup.Key;
            foreach (var setting in settingsGroup.Value)
            {
                var jProperty = setting as JProperty;
                Data.Add($"{settingsGroupName}:{jProperty.Name.ToString()}", jProperty.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        return this;
    }

    protected string GetResponse(string resourceName)
    {
        var assembly = SettingsType.Assembly;
        var resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(SettingsType.Namespace+'.'+ "appsettings.json");
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

it is working for me but still looking for some better ways to do it.