# ExecutionContext return null when published for Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I need to get the directory of the folder for when the Azure Function is published. That directory will look something like `home\site\wwwroot`. I have learned a good practice to get the folder is by using the `ExecutionContext.FunctionDirectory` to recieve the directory. So I used this in the code like following:

```
                    var context = new ExecutionContext();
                    _applicationDirectory = context.FunctionAppDirectory;

                    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(_applicationDirectory)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .Build();
```

I tried to publish and test this, but it returns `null`.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to recieve my directory so I can set the base path to the currenct directory.

I have so far tried the code I provided just above. I have read a few StackOverFlows suggestion aswell, but without luck. Some suggest to use the `FunctionAppDirectory` instead, but this resulted in the same issue.

Regarding debugging on Azure Portal, neither the Logs or Live Metrics provides anything else than the null exception.

Comment: Can I ask why you need to get that folder name? Just wanting to understand what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @Skin When publishing Azure Function, it changes the configurations for where other files are. In my case, I need to access my appsettings.json. But the configuration are set to be on a local device, and not Azure published version. So I need to configurate it to look at the current directory it is in to be able to find the file.

Comment: Should your appsettings not be included on the app configuration blade in Azure or am I simplifying your solution?

Comment: Haha, I had the same thought, and it is. But the problem is not where the files are, it is the Azure Function in Azure Portal thinking it is in another directory.  So I need to tell it to look at what it is in now, if it is local, debug, cloud or someting else.

Comment: Local vs Cloud, you can still use them accordingly ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal ... `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`

Comment: @Skin You can't, because the directory is different - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47784808/could-not-load-the-appsettings-json-file-when-function-deployed-to-azure. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function

Comment: No but my point is, don’t read the file, use the environment variables functionality built into functions.

Comment: @Skin I might be mistaken, but as shown in my question, I will need to set the `.SetBasePath` for it to load my appsettings.json?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. The way I first thought was the correct possible way, is not the way to do it. By using the following code, I am able to recive the folder `C\home\wwwroot`:

```
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string path = fileInfo.Directory.Parent.FullName;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

I tried the below C# with **logging method** to get my Function Directory:-

```cs
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyFunctionApp
{
    public static class MyHttpTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("MyHttpTrigger")]
        public static IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
            ExecutionContext context)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var functionDirectory = context.FunctionAppDirectory;
            log.LogInformation($"Function directory: {functionDirectory}");

            return new OkObjectResult($"Function directory: {functionDirectory}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Local Output:-**

[image]

***Then I published this function to my FunctionApp in Azure portal and Tested the function, I got the results below:-***

**Portal Output:-**

[image]

Comment: I am affraid the output is still null for some odd reason.

Comment: @AlexanderThomsen Did you use the code to trigger HTTP function same as posted in the answer?

Comment: The Function is a Time Trigger. And I tried your solution both local and published. It worked local, but not in Azure. Local, it showed my local diretory, and null in Azure. So same problem.

Comment: @AlexanderThomsen Are you using a consumption-based plan for your function app?

Comment: It is, I use the pay-as-you-use.

Comment: Which plan did you use while creating your function app? I am using Windows Based Consumption plan for my function app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253132/discussion-between-dasari-kamali-and-alexander-thomsen).